# Создать массив из массива объектов

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как из массива объектов

```
[
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Академія Південний"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Школа Південний Основний склад"
  }
]
```

создать массив такого плана `["8", "15"]`

Answer (score 4):

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Академія Південний"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Школа Південний Основний склад"
  }
];

const newArr = arr.map(item => item.id.toString());
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: а зачем `slice`?

Comment: `const newArr = arr.map(item => item.id.toString());` так тоже переварит же

Answer (score 1):

```
let newArray = [];

array.forEach((obj) => newArray.push(obj.id));
```

Comment: нет смысла использовать forEach так как есть map, который возвращает новый массив